# Conflict headers from different OpenSSL version

Tags: makefile, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install OpenSSL 1.0.2k on Ubuntu 14.04 from sources. I already have 1.0.1f version. After *./config* I run *make* and get next message:

```
cryptlib.c:1019:5: error: conflicting types for 'CRYPTO_memcmp'
int CRYPTO_memcmp(const volatile void *in_a, const volatile void *in_b, size_t len)
 ^
In file included from cryptlib.h:72:0,
             from cryptlib.c:117:
/usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:582:5: note: previous declaration of 'CRYPTO_memcmp' was here
int CRYPTO_memcmp(const void *a, const void *b, size_t len);
```

*make report* shows:

```
#include uses headers from different OpenSSL version!
```

How to set right headers for compiler? My PATH is:

```
usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are not revealing some interesting piece of information. I can't duplicate on a machine with both the distro copy and Master available (and using `OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable`). Did you `cd` into the `openssl-1.0.2k` directory before `config` and `make`? Are there whitespaces in the path? Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Yes I did `cd` into `openssl-1.0.2k` before `config` and `make`. There are no whitespaces in the path. Thank you, I will read OpenSSL wiki again and again, until I not understand.

Comment: The message *"#include uses headers from different OpenSSL version!"* is coming from [`util/selftest.pl`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/util/selftest.pl). There's something missing from your question. Please show the exact commands you are using, and please echo your PATH and add it to the question. I think we also need to see the full output of `./config`.

Comment: It's all the commands I've typed, there's nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was resolved by updating the package to OpenSSL-1.0.2g from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:0k53d-karl-f830m/openssl 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openssl
```